# Is this test muddying the water?

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, medicine

In the case of a neurological disease called idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus, if the patient is suspected positive for the condition, they are administered a test called the spinal tap test. In a review paper the conservative estimates for this test is as follows:

- Sensitivity: 26%
- Specificity: 33%
- Positive predictive value: 73%

Now by computing these numbers backwards, using for example a nomogram such as this one: https://mclibrary.duke.edu/sites/mclibrary.duke.edu/files/public/guides/nomogram.pdf

We can compute the LLR+ to be around 0.4 on a positive test.

This means their pre-test probability was around 85%. This is **higher** than their post-test probability on a positive test.

Does this mean this test is simply muddying the water and there was higher indication before the test to treat, than after, even with a positive test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This means their pre-test probability was around 85%. This is higher than their post-test probability on a positive test"

If this statement is true, then yes, the test in question is worthless. Still, it would be interesting to know about the reliability of those estimates as well as statistical significance of that difference